# Do airports archive the registration numbers of arriving and departing flights, and if so, for how long?

Tags: aircraft-identification, aircraft-registration

I am researching a flight I took as a child from LAX to Copenhagen in 1960 in a SAS DC-7C. I know the flight number, route, stops, departure time and date and wish to identify specifically which of SAS's -7C's I was on- either by the Danish registration number or the plane's "viking designator"- Frede Viking, Rolf Viking, etc.

I know this is a long shot- but my question is: Do airports archive the registration numbers of arriving and departing flights, and if so, for how long?

By the way I am in touch with both SAS's corporate office and their museum in Oslo, Norway on this matter.

Comment: I'm sure that airports keep records for tax and regulatory compliance, and that they will keep these for a number of years. I can't see why airports in general would keep them for sixty years. However, what 'airports' do is not really pertinent to your problem. It's the records kept by the airports visited by your aircraft on that flight that interest you and only the airports involved would know what records they have. You should contact them.

Comment: I would guess that you are more likely to get an answer by contacting SAS directly than by getting in touch with the airports. Since you've done that, I'd say you're on your way, and it would be cool if you would stop back by to at least let us know if they had the info.